# jQuery selector: addressing a submit button by ID fails

Tags: jquery-selectors

Given a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="AddToCart" size="2" id="AddToCart" />
```

why wouldn't this code disable the button:

```
$('#AddToCart').attr(disabled, 'disabled');
```

mny thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute name passed to [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) needs to be in quotes, like this:

```
$('#AddToCart').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
//or without quotes, as an object:
$('#AddToCart').attr({ disabled: 'disabled' });
```

Also make sure this is running in a `document.ready` event handler, or somewhere else after the element is ready, e.g.:

```
$(function() {
  $('#AddToCart').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```