# How to select specific button with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a situation here . i am fetching some data from DB and i iterate it in a JSP page in a HTML table and so wverything is dynamic . Since there are multiple entries so i am confused how to select particular entry via jquery selector and then do some basic stuff

JSP code :

```
<td height="40px" class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><a href="  <%=contextName%>/jsp/knowledgeBase/kbDetails.jsp?kbaseID=<%=kbaseID%>&app=<%=motsID%>&env=<%=env%>&env=<%=env%>&ptitle"=<%=pTitle%>><%=kbaseID%></a></td>

<td height="40px" class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><%=motsName%></td>

<td height="40px" class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <%=problemDescription%></td>

<td height="40px" class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><%=solution%><button value="Expand" id="Exp">Expand</button></td>
```

Since i have dynamic variables in this how do i write the jquery code to pic up the **particular button** and display result in **particular `<td>`**

Basically i want to use the `accordion` functionality
below is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector: addressing a submit button by ID fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553093/jquery-selector-addressing-a-submit-button-by-id-fails)

Answer (score 1):

<del>By giving each button a different class, and then doing  $(.classname)

(or give them an id and use $(#idname)</del>

**EDIT: (thanks, Sebastian S)**
By giving each button a different id, and then doing  `$(#classname)`

Comment: for uniqueness only use IDs. classes serve a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Either use different `id` for every cell, or if it is more appropriate, you can use HTML5 `data-*` attributes instead.

#### Usage

If you are using `id`, you can get the particular buttons by

```
document.getElementById('myId'); // vanilla JS
$('#myId'); // jquery
```

In case of `data-*` attributes:

```
document.querySelector('td[data-myAttr=myVal]'); // vanilla JS
$('td[data-myAttr=myVal]'); // jquery
```

Data attributes make better sense, if the particular cells are not identified by a single identifier, but multiple fields.